# How to escape HTML special characters in Java?

Tags: java, html

Is there a way to convert a string to a string that will display properly in a web document?  For example, changing the string

```
"<Hello>"
```

To

```
"&lt;Hello&gt;"
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`StringEscapeUtils` has functions designed exactly for this:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html

Comment: This link doesn't work anymore. The class can be found here http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html and the project containing it is here http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/

Comment: @Jakub Thanks. Updated the post with the newer URL.

Answer (score 3):

That's usually called "HTML escaping". I'm not aware of anything in the standard libraries for doing this (though you can approximate it by using XML escaping). There are lots of third-party libraries that can do this, however. [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) from org.apache.commons.lang has a `escapeHtml` method that can do this.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static String stringToHTMLString(String string) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(string.length());
    // true if last char was blank
    boolean lastWasBlankChar = false;
    int len = string.length();
    char c;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
        c = string.charAt(i);
        if (c == ' ') {
            // blank gets extra work,
            // this solves the problem you get if you replace all
            // blanks with &nbsp;, if you do that you loss 
            // word breaking
            if (lastWasBlankChar) {
                lastWasBlankChar = false;
                sb.append("&nbsp;");
                }
            else {
                lastWasBlankChar = true;
                sb.append(' ');
                }
            }
        else {
            lastWasBlankChar = false;
            //
            // HTML Special Chars
            if (c == '"')
                sb.append("&quot;");
            else if (c == '&')
                sb.append("&amp;");
            else if (c == '<')
                sb.append("&lt;");
            else if (c == '>')
                sb.append("&gt;");
            else if (c == '\n')
                // Handle Newline
                sb.append("&lt;br/&gt;");
            else {
                int ci = 0xffff & c;
                if (ci < 160 )
                    // nothing special only 7 Bit
                    sb.append(c);
                else {
                    // Not 7 Bit use the unicode system
                    sb.append("&#");
                    sb.append(new Integer(ci).toString());
                    sb.append(';');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Unicode supplementary characters are encoded as 2 chars in a String and this will not render that correctly. To support unicode really you need to deal with code points, not chars.

Comment: Hey I know this is an old q but was wondering - why would the String.replaceAll() method not work instead of going through the characters one by one?

Answer (score 1):

HTMLEntities is an Open Source Java class that contains a collection of static methods (htmlentities, unhtmlentities, ...) to convert special and extended characters into HTML entitities and vice versa.

http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=htmlentities

Answer (score 0):

Better do it yourself, if you know the logic behind - it is easy:

```
 public class ConvertToHTMLcode {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
          String specialSymbols = "ễ%ß Straße";
          System.out.println(convertToHTMLCodes(specialSymbols)); //&#7877;%&#223;
   }

   public static String convertToHTMLCodes(String str) throws IOException {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      int len = str.length();
      for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
          char c = str.charAt(i);
         if (c > 127) {
            sb.append("&#");
            sb.append(Integer.toString(c, 10));
            sb.append(";");
        } else {
            sb.append(c);
        }
     }
       return sb.toString();
   }
}
```