# Java se file.txt convert to file.html

Tags: java

How to convert txt to html with all words of file.txt ?

```
public class Main {

    private static String name = "writer.html";
    private static String Text = "C://Users//Vladimir//IdeaProjects//Algorithms//src//pack/textfile.txt";

    public static String readtxt(String filename) throws IOException{

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        String s;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(s + "\n");
        }

        reader.close();
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static Object writer(String fileName,String text){
        Text = text;
        try {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File(fileName));
            try {
                out.print(Text);
            } finally {
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

writer.html (output - C://Users//Vladimir//IdeaProjects//Algorithms//src//pack/textfile.txt )

Comment: are you looking for conver from .txt to .html right ?

Comment: This is a lots of efforts just to copy a file. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Create a file.html and copy all text from textfile.txt to file.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are missing quite a lot in your code, and that you are on a learning path. If your class is not complete I'd suggest you take a look first how to correctly read from one file and write into another, like this:

[File I/O: Reading from one file and writing to another (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588525/file-i-o-reading-from-one-file-and-writing-to-another-java)

or just educate your self on [File I/O in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

In case you have that already covered, and you are wondering how to transfer from simple text file to html, I'd suggest next to look at HTML format as you should create valid html file (where the content of your text file will be copied into `<body>` element ) - http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

Once you inject that into your target file you can start adding line by line from your txt file. For the sake of simplicity lets assume all your text will be inside single paragraph html element then you will separate each line using `<br>`

tag (as vishal mentioned).

For 'advanced' transformation you should escape your strings so that all words are correctly diplayed in the browser using something like [Commons StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) - or check this thread:[How to escape HTML special characters in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224996/java-convert-string-to-html-string)

Good luck

Comment: is this helpfull or you would prefere complete code? :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all change this,

From -

```
sb.append(s + "\n");
```

To -

```
sb.append(s + "<br/>");
```

Also remove this,

> Text = text; // not needed

change over here like,

```
out.print(text);
```

I think it should be work properly as per your requirement.

Comment: output text from textfile.txt

Comment: you want output text/htmlfile from textfile.txt. please be clear i am unable to understand what exactly you want